# Retrieve specific jar from ant ivy

Tags: ant, ivy

I use ant + ivy for a project. So lets assume I need to run `<sql` task for ant, thus I need to fetch jdbc driver 1st. Furthermore the driver is required during compiling the project. So I want to have 2 configuration:

- **default**: to retrieve jdbc driver and other project dependencies
- **jdbc**: to retrieve ONLY jdbc driver.

And then just run retrieve task with different configurations like that:

```
<!--Fetch all project dependencies, including jdbc driver-->
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.lib.home}/[artifact].[ext]" conf="default" />


<!-- Fetch only jdbc driver-->
<ivy:retrieve pattern="${build.lib.home}/[artifact].[ext]" conf="jdbc" />
```

**ivy.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivy-module version="2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ant.apache.org/ivy/schemas/ivy.xsd">
    <info organisation="" module="notebook-ivy"/>

    <configurations>
        <conf name="default" visibility="public" extend="jdbc"/>
        <conf name="jdbc" visibility="public"/>
    </configurations>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.6" conf="jdbc->default"/>
        <dependency org="org.apache.camel" name="camel-core" rev="2.15.1"/>

    </dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

I'm using public mavencentral so I can't change dependency configuration on server:
**ivysettings.xml**

```xml
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="chain"/>
  <resolvers>
    <chain name="chain">
      <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true" root="http://central.maven.org/maven2/"/>
    </chain>
  </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

The configuration described above works. But It looks confusing, when *default extends jdbc* and *jdbc extends default* simultaneously. I'm new to ivy, so my question is: if this's the right way of using configurations for ivy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "extends" operation enables you to perform a union set operation on jars within an ivy configuration, so this would work fine.

My preference is to model configurations on my anticipated classpath requirements:

```
<configurations>
    <conf name="compile" description="Dependencies required to build project"/>
    <conf name="compile" description="Dependencies required to run project" extends="compile"/>
    <conf name="test" description="Dependencies required to test project" extends="runtime"/>
    <conf name="build" description="ANT build tasks"/>
</configurations>
```

The ivy cachepath task can then be used to create these paths within the build file:

```
  <target name="resolve">
    <ivy:resolve/>

    <ivy:cachepath pathid="build.path" conf="build"/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path" conf="compile"/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path" conf="test"/>
  </target>
```

This approach means something like a jdbc jar would be mapped to a "compile" configuration, making it available for javac tasks:

```
  <target name="compile" depends="resolve">
    ..
    <javac ... classpathref="compile.path"/>
  </target>
```

But also included in the "runtime" configuration that gets saved to disk as a dependency when building the jar package:

```
  <target name="build" depends="compile">
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${dist.dir}/lib/[artifact].[ext]" conf="runtime"/>

    <manifestclasspath property="jar.classpath" jarfile="${dist.jar}">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${dist.dir}/lib" includes="*.jar"/>
      </classpath>
    </manifestclasspath>

    <jar destfile="${dist.jar}" basedir="${build.dir}/classes">
      <manifest>
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${dist.main.class}"/>
        <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>
      </manifest>
    </jar>
  </target>
```